# PHP Average of daily averages pulled from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm calculating daily averages of $spent in a table using mysql. In php, I'd like to average all those daily averages into 1 average daily average. Eventually, I'd like to do this for multiple tables and graph the final averages in highcharts. Right now, I can't get php to average the results of my query. I am connecting to my database, but just not showing it in the code. See code below:

```
<?php

    function array_average($arr){
        $sum = array_sum($arr);
        $num = sizeof($arr);
        echo $sum/$num;
    }

    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT round((sum(d_power),2) as $perton FROM pheom.pheom_gb WHERE timestamp between subdate(curdate(), interval 3 month) and curdate() GROUP BY Day(timestamp) ORDER BY Timestamp");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
        $rows['data'][] = $r['$perton'];
    }

    echo array_average($rows);

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not do the calculation in SQL?

```
select avg($perton) as $perton
from (SELECT round(sum(d_power), 2) as $perton
      FROM pheom.pheom_gb
      WHERE timestamp between subdate(curdate(), interval 3 month) and curdate()
      GROUP BY Day(timestamp)
     ) t;
```

Comment: This would be a great alternative. But I can't get it to work in mysql. I'm getting error: every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: @user2686567 . . . Do you have the final `t` after the closing paren?

Answer (score 0):

Where is `$perton` coming from?  Your query is in double quotes, meaning the variable is being expanded, but your array access is in single quotes so it is not.

If `$perton` is not defined, then I believe your query will be evaluated as:

```
SELECT round((sum(d_power),2) as FROM pheom.pheom_gb WHERE timestamp between subdate(curdate(), interval 3 month) and curdate() GROUP BY Day(timestamp) ORDER BY Timestamp
```

Which is a syntax error.

Additionally, I don't think `array_sum` works with multidimensional arrays.  I would try:

```
echo array_average( $rows['data'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with PHP or any other scripting language for that matter. This is exactly the kind of thing you should always try to solve within your DB query - you'll get cleaner solutions and much better performance than passing all data to your script just to make a calculation you could've gotten with a single query in the first place. The answer given by Gordon Linoff is the right one.